# How do I import a split_config.$arch.apk in Android.bp?

Tags: android, apk, android-soong

> Android.bp

```
android_app_import {
name: "Wikipedia",
apk: "Wikipedia.apk",
dpi_variants: {
    xhdpi: {
        apk: "split_config.xhdpi.apk",
    },
},
arch_variants: {
    armeabi_v7a: {
        apk: "split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk",
    },
},
dex_preopt: {
    enabled: false,
},
presigned : true,
product_specific: true,
```

}

How can I add a dependency apk which is the spit config. I can only import the dpi variant what about variant apks and language apks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "arch_variants", just use "arch". See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium-webview/+/refs/tags/android-r-beta-2/Android.bp

Comment: So how language specfic?